# XQuery function to fetch value from XML using XPath dynamically

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

How to write a function in XQuery to fetch price of Book in below XML whose name is `x` using XPath?

```
    <Bookstore>
     <Book>
       <Name>A</Name>
       <Price>15</Price>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Name>B</Name>
        <Price>10</Price>
    </Book>
  </Bookstore>
```

XPath to retrieve would be with name value pair like below

```
Bookstore/Book[Name/text()='A']/Price/text()
```

Please help

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. If "x" is simply a string giving the name of the book that you want to retrieve, then declare x as an external global variable and use `Book[Name=$x]` (no need for the `text()`, by the way). You say you want to evaluate a dynamically-supplied XPath expression but you haven't made it clear why you think you need this for this particular problem.

Comment: I want a function which returns value of the xpath in an xml. This xpath itself should be passed as a argument to the function

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
/bookstore/book/price/text()
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: Hi this will return both 15 and 10. I want only 15 to be returned. In this case my xpath is correct but I want it to sent from a config file as input to a function which will return the value by xquerying the XML with xpath tat is passed as argument

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to write an XQuery function to fetch price of a book by its name, using your XML structure:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare function local:get-book-price($book-name as xs:string) as xs:string {
    let $bookstore := 
        <Bookstore>
            <Book>
                <Name>A</Name>
                <Price>15</Price>
            </Book>
            <Book>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Price>10</Price>
            </Book>
        </Bookstore>
    return
        $bookstore/Book[Name eq $book-name]/Price/string()
};

local:get-book-price("A")
```

This will return `15`.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret you correctly (and I'm still having difficulty) you are looking for an `eval()` function that takes an XPath expression in the form of a string, and evaluates it, returning the result of the XPath expression.

Your use case really doesn't explain WHY you need this, though there are plenty of problems that do.

There's no `eval()` function in the standard XQuery function library. Some implementations have one, for example Saxon has `saxon:evaluate()`. The XSLT 3.0 specification has a standard instruction, `xsl:evaluate` - it's an instruction rather than a function because of the need to establish the context for evaluation.